# How to implement graph database with a Parse backend?

Tags: rest, neo4j, cloud

I need to have a graph database which contains connected friendlist of facebook users which use my android app. Not necessarily a graph, any ways to maintain a connected friend list and relations among them are welcome.

A person does a facebook login to my android app which has a Parse based mobile backend. This backend will be communicating to a graph database of facebook friendlists, to create and retrive nodes/relations. I spent hours with graphenedb/neo4j/heroku and couldn't lift off. Need a pointer to a quick way or a totally different approach. The volume will be less as it is just a POC now. Moreover, the database must be deploy friendly to quickly test the POC.

Comment: The choice of a Graph Database depends on your level of expertise with graph databases, use case and volume of data. Could you provide some context around these? *Easily implementable on some cloud server* may not provide the same.

Comment: Thanks rhetonik. Volume is low as of now as it is POC. A person does a facebook login to android app which has a Parse based mobile backend. This backend will be communicating to a graph database of facebook friendlists, to create and retrive nodes/relations. I spent hours with graphenedb and couldn't lift off. Need a pointer to a quick way or a totally different approach.

Answer (score 2):

Go with http://www.graphenedb.com/, it's a Neo4j instance running in the cloud. For more detailed answer your question should be more detailed.

Comment: I started with graphenedb, but even after spending hours, I was not able to deploy something on heroku which they support. I want suggestions like graphenedb but it seems like requests like these are not to be made to stackoverflow :(

Comment: What were your problems deploying to heroku? Perhaps use their support system?

Comment: I was able to deploy Neo4J to an Azure VM. I wanted to check if someone had already an easy deployment going on and could share knowledge. 1. I created a cloudservice in Azure. 2. Added Ubuntu VM and enabled SSH access using endpoints. 3. I wrote cloudcode in parse to contact PHP on Ubuntu VM which in the backend makes edits/retrieves neo4j nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The original comment is accurate - there's many factors involved. See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database

for a reasonable listing of software, including a simple feature grid.  The term 'easily implementable' is such an arbitrary measurement, there really isn't a good way to help.

Comment: True DanG. This was my first question on stackoverflow and I have made edits to original question w.r.t. the expectations.